# Prove that $\mathbb L^{-1}\{\mathbb p^\mathbb k\}=0$

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

There is a question in my book at the end of which it is written that $\mathbb L^{-1}\{\mathbb p^\mathbb k\}=0$ for $\mathbb k$= 0,1,2,.....

But we know that $\mathbb L\{\mathbb 0\}$ = $\mathbb 0$
So here laplace transformation isn't one to one so how the inverse laplace transformation exists?

- How do I prove $\mathbb L^{-1}\{\mathbb p^\mathbb k\}=0$ ?

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BLCS_20Z5Q4snbMKgwzlgQIh89D7l9P3/view?usp=drivesdk)

[Original problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16uX3EM8j5DKRq1oUuTsNKuibotyFKVRL/view?usp=drivesdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know $$\mathbb L[\delta(t)]=1\\\mathbb L[f'(t)]=s\mathbb L[f(t)](s)-f(0^+)$$
So $$\mathbb L^{-1}[s]=\mathbb L^{-1}\left[\mathbb L[\delta'(t)]-\delta(0^+)\right]=\delta'(t)$$ Similarly, $$\mathbb L^{-1}(s^k)=\delta^{(k)}(t)$$

However we use Laplace transforms on functions which are only non-zero for $t>0$, which is why we would then take $$\mathbb L^{-1}(s^k)=\left[\delta^{(k)}(t)\right]_{t>0}=0$$

Comment: Thank you sir !! I understood. But why the inverse laplace transformation exist

Comment: It exists because [the Bromwich integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform#Mellin's_inverse_formula) 'converges' (in the sense of a distribution).

Comment: But what is wrong with my argument ?

Comment: Nothing is wrong - the inverse Laplace transforms are actually both different (as I showed, this gives a delta function rather than $0$, but in the context of the problem, they both have the same effect on the final answer. However, the inverse Laplace transform of $s^k$ is not actually exactly equal to $0$.

Comment: sir did you downvote my question?

Comment: nope, i haven't looked at this since last week.